# Declaring a structure inside a structure?

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm working om a simple program that creates rooms in a house according to a map. For every room, i list the connected rooms. The thing is, this cannot compile. Any idea why ?

```
typedef struct s_room {
    char *name;
    int nbr;
    int x;
    int y;
    bool start;
    bool end;
    int ants;
    int current;
    t_room *connect;
    int visited;

} t_room;
```

I think it comes from the `t_room *connect`, but I can't figure out how to solve this.

Comment: well if it doesn't compile, it also shows the error. You can also paste the error in your question

Comment: @unwind It's similar, but not quite the same - here's only 1 struct.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
typedef struct      s_room
{
    ....
    t_room          *connect;
    ....
}                   t_room;
```

with

```
typedef struct      s_room
{
    ....
    struct s_room   *connect;
    ....
}                   t_room;
```

Comment: It would be much better to explain what the problem is rather than just giving a fix.

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

1. Forward declaration of type

   ```
   typedef struct      s_room t_room;
   struct s_room {
       t_room          *connect;
   };
   ```
2. Use of `struct s_room`

   ```
   typedef struct s_room {
       struct s_room  *connect;
   } t_room;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the structure type `t_room` to define the type `t_room` itself because it is not yet defined. Therefore you should replace this

```
t_room *connect;
```

with

```
struct s_room *connect;
```

Or you can `typedef` `struct s_room` type before actually defining `struct s_room`. Then you can use the type alias in the definition.

```
// struct s_room type is not defined yet.
// create an alias s_room_t for the type.

typedef struct s_room s_room_t; 

// define the struct s_room type and
// create yet another alias t_room for it.

typedef struct s_room {
    // other data members
    s_room_t *connect; 

    // note that type of connect is not yet defined
    // because struct s_room of which s_room_t is an alias
    // is not yet fully defined.

} t_room;

// s_room_t and t_room are both aliases for the type struct s_room
```

Personally, I'd prefer the former because to do the latter, you have to introduce one extra `typedef` just to define the other `typedef`! This looks like namespace clutter without any real benefit.